# Batch script to run sql scripts in Oracle for different schemas

Tags: oracle, batch-file, jenkins

I am currently looking for batch script which does the following:

1. Accepts variables from a text file with the following format:

> ```
> ..\xxx.sql<space>schema
> ..\xxx.pkb<space>schema
> ..\xxx.pks<space>schema
> ..\xxx.prc<space>schema
> ```

2. Connects to the instance based on the schema name provided in the text file. I only have 1 DB node.
3. Executes the files in sequence and commits them to the database

This is what I managed to have done so far. However this doesn't support different schemas/passwords.

```
@echo off

SET SCHEMA_NAME=Test_123
SET PASSWORD=1234

echo ================================================
echo Identifying files to be written into database...
echo ================================================
echo.
rem -- Display list of files in the deployment directory
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
echo.
echo.
echo ================================================
echo Establishing connection to Elixir UAT DB...
echo ================================================
echo.
rem -- Change working directory to which the sqlplus.exe resides
Pushd C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN
rem -- Makes SQLPlus exits upon completion of the executing the files
rem -- This assist the user without modifying each sql file ending with 'exit' command
echo exit | sqlplus %SCHEMA_NAME%/%PASSWORD%@TESTUATDB @C:\Users\Desktop\Driver.sql

cmd /k


Driver.sql:
@C:\Users\sgarmkez\Desktop\ShowTimeStamp.sql
@C:\Users\sgarmkez\Desktop\ShowTimeStamp2.sql
```

Once completed, I will use Jenkins to create a job which calls this batch file to perform deployments into the Oracle database. Please let me know if there are other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Following code can help you in Linux:

```
#! /bin/bash  

SCHEMA_NAME=schema
PASSWORD=password
IP=127.0.0.1
PORT=1521
SID=orcl

for SQLFile in `cat ./listof_sql_files.txt`
do
    sqlplus $SCHEMA_NAME/$PASSWORD@$IP:$PORT/$SID @$j
done
```

In Windows, following piece of code can help:

FOR /F %%sqlfile IN (listof_sql_files.txt) DO sqlplus username/password@127.0.0.1:1521/orcl @%%sqlfile

Note:
You need to put your schema, password, IP, port and SID
Also consider the file based on your file location in the system.

Comment: He asked for a batch script, not a bash script. There is a huge difference.

Comment: Thank you SomethingDark for pointing about bash and batch script.

Comment: For some reasons when I executed your command, it can't locate %%sqlfile and the batch file exits from cmd. And how does this supports multiple usernames/passwords?

Comment: @marcus.k - Please confirm that you have kept list of sql files in listof_sql_files.txt file and ensure .bat file is executed from the same directory where you have listof_sql_files.txt file.